# Concatenating text-box values and displaying in a paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `map()` to collect the text-box values into an array, and then printing the values in a paragraph successfully.

```
$("p")
  .append($("input").map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  })
  .get()
  .join(", "));
```

However I want to store the concatenated values in a variable before showing it on the screen, so that I can re-use the value later. How can I store this value without appending it to the `<p>` tag?

Comment: can you better explain the output?  what do you expect to see and what do you actually see?  Where do you expect "two lines"?  is it one line between each input?

Comment: I think this will be the simple way to do it , only one suggestion change `return $(this).val();` to `return this.value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. For anybody with a similar need, I did this:

```
var x = $("input").map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
      })
      .get().join(", ");

$("p").append(x);
```